# How to host a site using apache2 on Ubuntu 20.04 with ip_adress/phpmyadmin accessible

Tags: apache2, 20.04, lamp, phpmyadmin, virtualhost

I have a VPS setup with Ubuntu 20.04 and LAMP installed. I could access phpmyadmin then via `<ip_address>/phpmyadmin`.

Later I enabled a `virtualhost` at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` by adding `.conf` file, I can access the site I enabled via `<ip_address>`

But  `<ip_address>/phpmyadmin` now gives a 404. As I understand this is because all the requests are directed to my enabled site. Since I want to access both phpmyadmin and mysite as well, I tried few combinations of changes to `.conf` file as suggested from search results I got from Google. But none of them worked.  Three of the tried configurations are as follow.

**Adding an alias**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin john@ubuntu

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cpapp-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cpapp-access.log combined

    Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
   </Directory>

    <Location />
            ProxyPass unix:/home/john/cpapp/cpapp.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
            ProxyPassReverse unix:/home/john/cpapp/cpapp.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Creating two virtual hosts**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin john@ubuntu

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cpapp-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cpapp-access.log combined

    <Location />
            ProxyPass unix:/home/john/cpapp/cpapp.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
            ProxyPassReverse unix:/home/john/cpapp/cpapp.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Limiting my Site to a specific URL path** - this gave an syntax error of `.conf` when reloading apache2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin john@ubuntu

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cpapp-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/cpapp-access.log combined

    <Location />
            ProxyPass /mysite/ unix:/home/john/cpapp/cpapp.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
            ProxyPassReverse /mysite/ unix:/home/john/cpapp/cpapp.sock|http://127.0.0.1/
    </Location>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Can somebody please point me what I have tried wrong?

**Configuration in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf`**

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration

Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    # limit libapache2-mod-php to files and directories necessary by pma
   <IfModule mod_php7.c>
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
        php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/phpseclib/:/usr/share/php>
   </IfModule>

</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/templates>
Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

When installing phpMyAdmin it is usually shipped with a configuration file for Apache - `/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf`. If this file is not present, try to enable it with the following commands:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin
sudo systemctl restart apaache2
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. The configuration file is already available in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf` what changes do I need to do it?

Comment: I posted the configurations if you can have a look

Comment: Did you enable the configuration with `a2enconf`?